# Knockout - Updating observableArray of Models

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0

I am trying to solve a problem with knockout. What I am trying to do is having a root model, containing an observableArray of another model. This model also contains an observableArray of one last model (called "Result"). 
Depending on the user interactions, the first observableArray can be completely changed (resetting the array and adding other models).

A list is rendered to the user and he is able to filter the Results with a text field (I am using a computed to filter).

The problem that I am facing is that even if I reset the observableArray, it seems that references are kept to the nested models, and knockout continues to fire events on these models, which leads to making more and more Javascript calls as the user changes the list.

I have written a small jsfiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/PNzM5/
Here is the javascript code :

```
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function (valuesToPush) {
    var underlyingArray = this();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
};

function Result(value) {
    this.value = ko.observable(value);
}

function NestedItem(name, currentValue) {
    var _this = this;
    this.currentValue = currentValue;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.totalResults = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.filteredResults = ko.computed(function () {
        console.log('get called by ' + _this.name());
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(_this.totalResults(), function (result) {
            return result.value().toLowerCase().indexOf(_this.currentValue()) != -1;
        });
    });
}

function Model() {
    var _this = this;
    this.nestedItemList = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.currentValue = ko.observable("");

    this.createFirstList = function () {
        this.nestedItemList([]);
        _this.createItem("sublist 1", [new Result("value 1"), new Result("value 2"), new Result("value 3")]);
        _this.createItem("sublist 2", [new Result("value 4"), new Result("value 5"), new Result("value 6")]);
    }

    this.createSecondList = function () {
        this.nestedItemList([]);
        _this.createItem("sublist 3", [new Result("value 1"), new Result("value 2"), new Result("value 3")]);
        _this.createItem("sublist 4", [new Result("value 4"), new Result("value 5"), new Result("value 6")]);
    }

    this.createItem = function (name, values) {
        var item = new NestedItem(name, _this.currentValue);
        item.totalResults.pushAll(values);
        this.nestedItemList.push(item);
    }
}
```

and the relevant HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value:currentValue,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text" placeholder="Type to filter"/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: nestedItemList">
    <li class="sublist" data-bind="text: name"></li>
    <!-- ko foreach: filteredResults -->
    <li class="result" data-bind="text: value"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<button data-bind="event: {click: createFirstList}">First list</button>
<button data-bind="event: {click: createSecondList}">Second list</button>
```

I logged the calls to the computed to the console. If you click on "first list" and try to filter the result, you will see that for each character you type, the computed will be called for each list (which is fine). Then, if you click on "second list" and try to filter agin, you will see that the computed will be called 4 times. And you have 2 more calls each time you click on a button.

(my real models are far more complicated. For instance, Result contains far more properties)

What I get with my real models is IE8 telling me that a script is slowing down IE. And I suspect that this is the reason. Even if it's not, I would like to know why I am getting this behavior. Maybe that's more a Javascript problem than a Knockout problem? Or maybe I am doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.
In "NestedItem", I created a reset function that sets the results to an empty array:

```
this.reset = function() {
    _this.totalResults([]);
}
```

And I also created a reset function in the root model, that gets called each time a new list is created:

```
this.reset = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.nestedItemList(), function(list) {
        list.reset();
    });
    this.nestedItemList([]);
}
```

So, the models are now:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function(valuesToPush) {
    var underlyingArray = this();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
};

function Result(value) {
    this.value = ko.observable(value);
}

function NestedItem(name, currentValue) {
    var _this = this;
    this.currentValue = currentValue;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.totalResults = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.filteredResults = ko.computed(function() {
        console.log('get called by ' + _this.name());
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(_this.totalResults(), function(result) {
            return result.value().toLowerCase().indexOf(_this.currentValue()) != -1 ;
        });
    });
    this.reset = function() {
        _this.totalResults([]);
    }
}

function Model() {
    var _this = this;
    this.nestedItemList = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.currentValue = ko.observable("");

    this.createFirstList = function() {
        _this.reset();
        _this.createItem("sublist 1 title", [new Result("value 1"), new Result("value 2"), new Result("value 3")]);
        _this.createItem("sublist 2 title", [new Result("value 4"), new Result("value 5"), new Result("value 6")]);
    }

    this.createSecondList = function() {
        _this.reset();
        _this.createItem("sublist 3 title", [new Result("value 1"), new Result("value 2"), new Result("value 3")]);
        _this.createItem("sublist 4 title", [new Result("value 4"), new Result("value 5"), new Result("value 6")]);
    }

    this.reset = function() {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.nestedItemList(), function(list) {
            list.reset();
        });
        this.nestedItemList([]);
    }

    this.createItem = function(name, values) {
        var item = new NestedItem(name, _this.currentValue);
        item.totalResults.pushAll(values);
        this.nestedItemList.push(item);        
    }
}
```

I also reduced the number of observables in my real "Result" model (I had lots of observables and some of them did not need to be observables. Simple properties was enough. I am not getting IE error dialog anymore.
But still, I think that my solution is a bit hacky. If anyone has a better solution, I would be glad to see it. :)

**EDIT**: I forgot the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PNzM5/2/